# How to skip resource :create action when needed

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook, lwrp

I have a custom LWRP with just a `:create` action (which is also set to the default action).

Now every time I converge my node the action the LWRP action is performed adding to the final count of updated resources. I noticed that other resources have the message '(up to date)' on them, so I am wondering:

How can I prevent my LWRP from running if it is not necessary?

My LWRP is just a small set of standard Chef resources, so my guess is that there is a way to collect all their statuses and push it out of my wrapper resource.

Answer (score 0):

In your action method, you can just not do anything if the current state is fine. There are fancier ways using the why-run APIs, but that's the easier option.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution by using `use_inline_resources`. This will chain the update notification of the inner resources to the one on top.

This way the new_resource update attribute depends on the update status of the inner resources and triggers all possible side notifications.